# Nexmo not passing signature param to webhook callback

Tags: ruby, webhooks, vonage

I'm implementing a webhook callback in my Rails controller and I've attempted to follow the approach used in the rspec test that comes with the gem in order to verify the signature passed from Nexmo (see the 'check_signature method' test):

https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-ruby/blob/master/spec/nexmo/client_spec.rb

In my Nexmo API Settings, I added a Signature Secret (generated with Ruby Digest::MD5) to my account. I configured my webproxy with ngrok and on my Nexmo test number, I added the webhook callback generated by ngrok when it started up.

So, I try texting to my Nexmo phone number and Nexmo does push me a POST to my controller method however it does not contain a 'sig' or 'signature' parameter in the payload.

Unfortunately, I've not been able find much in the way of documentation on this specific feature. I may not be generating the Signature Secret correctly in my account on Nexmo. Most similar services actually generate these webhook validation secrets for you... not sure why Nexmo does not.

Anyway, if anyone has any suggestions, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to email support@nexmo.com with your API key and ask them to turn on webhook signatures.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I forgot to come back and answer.